# Why does a new Jeykll site work in Docker but not in my local environment?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I can serve a new Jekyll site in a Docker container like this.

```bash
docker run -it --rm ruby bash -c '
gem update --system
gem install jekyll

ruby --version
bundle --version
jekyll --version

jekyll new site
cd site
bundle exec jekyll serve
'
```

The container has these versions of Ruby, Bundler and Jekyll.

```
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x86_64-linux]
Bundler version 2.4.19
jekyll 4.3.2
```

Jekyll starts to serve the new site.

```
Configuration file: /site/_config.yml
            Source: /site
       Destination: /site/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts

<Snip some deprecation warnings>

Run in verbose mode to see all warnings.
                    done in 0.557 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/site'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

I try to repeat the same comamnds in my local environment.

```bash
env --chdir="$(mktemp --dir)" bash -c '
gem update --system
gem install jekyll

ruby --version
bundle --version
jekyll --version

jekyll new site
cd site
bundle exec jekyll serve
'
```

My local versions are exactly the same as the versions in Docker.

```
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x86_64-linux]
Bundler version 2.4.19
jekyll 4.3.2
```

Jekyll fails to serve the new site because it fails to read some internal file.

```
Configuration file: /tmp/tmp.dlivlJk8nJ/site/_config.yml
            Source: /tmp/tmp.dlivlJk8nJ/site
       Destination: /tmp/tmp.dlivlJk8nJ/site/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
             Error: could not read file /tmp/tmp.dlivlJk8nJ/site/vendor/install/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb: Invalid date '<%= Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') %>': Document 'vendor/install/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb' does not have a valid date in the YAML front matter.
             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    Invalid date '<%= Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') %>': Document 'vendor/install/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb' does not have a valid date in the YAML front matter.
                    ------------------------------------------------
      Jekyll 4.3.2   Please append `--trace` to the `serve` command 
                     for any additional information or backtrace. 
                    ------------------------------------------------

<Snip a stack trace.>
```

I don't know what else is different between the Docker environment and the local environment.

What do I need to change to make it work locally?

Comment: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/troubleshooting/#configuration-problems